# How to prevent users from accessing files in folder?

Tags: asp.net

I'm using Asp.Net Identity. I need to allow admins and deny users to access all pages in my management folder, so I've put a web.config file in that folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>
   <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin"/>
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
 </configuration>
```

But anybody can still access all files in folder. I've also tried to put it into main config file with location tag,but no results. Have you any ideas where to start looking for a problem?

Update: I've found a question on asp.net forum which explains a lot:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1955560.aspx?ASP+NET+Identity+Are+web+config+files+no+longer+acting+in+the+capacity+of+a+security+guard+for+our+ASP+NET+applications+files+and+folders+
There also one thing to mention. When creating new web application project with asp.net Identity. Visual Studio 2013 sets these parameters:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="None"/>
</system.web>
```

and

```
  <system.webServer>
   <modules>
     <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
   </modules>
  <system.webServer>
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to explain exactly what do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What happens and what do you think it should happen?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<configuration>

  <system.web>

    <authentication mode="Forms"/>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>  

    </authorization>
  </system.web>

  <location path="[mymanagementfolder]">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users ="?" />
        <allow users ="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

</configuration>
```

[MSDN SOURCE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871)

If **Directory Browsing** Is enabled in IIS then you should turn it **OFF**

**EDIT:**
I Think You Should Enable `Form/windows authentication`. Above code is working fine on My Computer as It redirects to `ReturnUrl`

[image: My Test output]

Comment: @JanBílek is Directory Browsing is enabled in IIS??

Answer (score 0):

change your code to ** ** it prevent any user that aren't authenticated:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>
   <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin"/>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
 </configuration>
```